# grunt writes content to console instead of file?

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I am trying to add `scss` to my grunt file so i ran the following command:
`npm install grunt-contrib-sass sass --save-dev`.
Then i added the following to my `Gruntfile.js`

`grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');` and

```
grunt.initConfig({
...
sass: {
    dev: {
        files: {
            '<%=meta.src %>assets/css/all2.css': '<%=meta.src %>assets/scss/build.scss'
        }
    },

    dist: {
        files: {
            '<%=meta.dist %>/assets/css/all.min.css': '<%=meta.src %>/assets/scss/build.scss'
        }
    }
},
```

When i run this i get the output of the `build.scss` in the console and it creates a empty file?

What am i missing????

```
Running "sass:dev" (sass) task
#flupdidup {
  font-weight: bold;
}
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
#flupdidup {
  font-weight: bold;
}
Done, without errors.
Process terminated with code 0.
```

a minimal recreation of the issue can be found here: https://github.com/Peter-Optiway/grunt-sass-issue

Comment: Can you remove `<%=meta.src %>` and see if it works fine?

Comment: @TarunLalwani sadly that didn't change any thing `'./app/assets/css/all2.css': './app/assets/scss/build.scss'`

Comment: Possible to get a minimal git repo for debugging?

Comment: @TarunLalwani https://github.com/Peter-Optiway/grunt-sass-issue when i open this up in visual studio and run sass:dev or sass:dist i get the error in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by changing to the `grunt-sass` package instead.

`npm install --save-dev load-grunt-tasks load-grunt-tasks`
Then i added the following to my `Gruntfile.js` `require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);` and it just worked.

Comment: Have a look at the answer I posted

Answer (score 3):

Switching to `grunt-sass` was always an option, but your issue was not because of that. The issue was because you had `sass` install using npm.

```
npm install -g sass
```

When you look at that

```
$ sass --help
Compile Sass to CSS.

Usage: dart-sass <input>

-s, --style         Output style.
                    [expanded (default)]

-c, --[no-]color    Whether to emit terminal colors.
    --[no-]trace    Print full Dart stack traces for exceptions.
-h, --help          Print this usage information.
    --version       Print the version of Dart Sass.
```

It has no output parameter. While `grunt-contrib-sass` expects the sass to be install from the ruby gem.

```
$ sudo gem install sass
```

Now sass will have different options

```
$ sass --help
Usage: sass [options] [INPUT] [OUTPUT]

Description:
  Converts SCSS or Sass files to CSS.
...
```

And now the build works fine

```
$ cat ./dist/assets/css/all.min.css
main #flupdidup {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #eeffcc; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=all.min.css.map */
```

Comment: In the end `grunt-sass` was a better option as it does not rely on ruby, but you get the 50 points for your effort!